# "does not designate any package" error, unable to use installed Cuda toolkit

Tags: common-lisp

I cloned the repo https://github.com/melisgl/higgsml.git and was trying to reproduce the result on my machine. When I tried to `$ make` at top level directory, this error message jumps out:

```
; compiling file "<top>/src/package.lisp" (written 12 DEC 2023 11:03:10 PM):
; compiling (DEFPACKAGE :HIGGS-BOSON ...)While evaluating the form starting at line 6, column 0
  of #P"<top>/quicklisp/local-projects/cl-cuda/cl-cuda.asd":
While evaluating the form starting at line 5, column 0
  of #P"<top>/quicklisp/local-projects/mgl-mat/mgl-mat.asd":
While evaluating the form starting at line 15, column 0
  of #P"<top>/build/load-project.lisp":
Unhandled LOAD-SYSTEM-DEFINITION-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {100399CBC3}>: Error while trying to load definition for system mgl-mat from pathname <top>/quicklisp/local-projects/mgl-mat/mgl-mat.asd: Error while trying to load definition for system cl-cuda from pathname <top>/quicklisp/local-projects/cl-cuda/cl-cuda.asd: The name "MGL-MAT" does not designate any package.
```

`<top>/src/package.lisp` defines a package `higgs-boson` with `(:use :cl :mgl-mat :mgl)` , so I think the key is that the compiler cannot find the definition for the package `mgl-mat`.

`mgl-mat.asd` defines a system named `mgl-mat`, and another file `<top>/quicklisp/local-projects/mgl-mat/src/package.lisp` defines the corresponding package, but using another package `mgl-pax` :

```
(mgl-pax:define-package :mgl-cube
  (:documentation "See MGL-CUBE:@CUBE-MANUAL.")
  (:use #:common-lisp #:mgl-pax))

(mgl-pax:define-package :mgl-mat
  (:documentation "See MGL-MAT:@MAT-MANUAL.")
  (:use #:common-lisp #:mgl-pax #:mgl-cube #:cl-cuda)
  (:import-from #:static-vectors #:static-vector #:static-vector-pointer))
```

`mgl-pax` can be loaded by `(ql:quickload :mgl-pax)`. If I simply add the ql loading and copy-paste this to `<top>/src/package.lisp` , it will instead say that `package MGL-PAX does not exist` .

If I try to load either `mgl-mat` or `cl-cuda` , it will report `system "cuda" not found` , though I did install Cuda 12.3 using `$ conda install cuda -c nvidia` , and `$ nvcc --version` produced the correct result (though it is in the default folder of Anaconda, instead of my <top> folder where everything else is stored).

So I wonder, what is the true reason for the error? How can I adjust the files so that the compiler correctly finds everything it needs?

Comment: Are you actually typing the `$`s? That's just a convention for "generic interactive shell prompt"; it indicates *where* the following command should be entered, it's not part of it.

Comment: Did you follow its README saying to run `make quicklisp`, to install everything below the top-level directory "with the exact versions with which this program was tested"?

Comment: @Shawn : Of course not; these are just used to indicate which are terminal commands.

Comment: @Ehvince : yes. I followed the instruction,  manually checked the directory, and I'm certain that everything necessary is at the right place, but the problem still persists.